# Non-static Data Member Initializers / Calling constructors of std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11

Code:

```
class A {
  std::vector<int> x = {2,3};                 // x[0] = 2 and x[1] = 3
  std::vector<int> y = std::vector<int>(2,3); // x[0] = 3 and x[1] = 3 Too verbose!!  
};
```

Is there a way that I can call the constructor of `std::vector<int>` only using brace initializer, or at least shorter version which gives the same effect?

I don't want to repeat `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: What's wrong with using a constructor initializer list?

Comment: @ildjarn I think I don't understand what you mean? Could you explain more specifically? My English is not very good.

Comment: @Sungmin: It would be: `class A { std::vector<int> y; public: A() : y(2,3) {} };`

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Thank you, I understand now. It is perfectly fine. But I just want to use non-static member initializer. This will improve the readability of my code a lot :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Is there any hack I could use?

If your only goal is to not having to *"explicitly"* specify the type twice you could use `decltype` to provide some aid in your quest:

```
class Obj {
  std::vector<int> v1 = decltype(v1) (2,3);
};
```

Also remember that `typedef`/`using` is a great way of not having to type<sup>1</sup> so much:

```
struct Obj {
   using VInt = std::vector<int>;
// typedef std::vector<int> VInt;

   VInt v = VInt (3,2);
};
```

<sup>1.</sup> <sub>pun not intended</sub>

---

### What does the standard say about it?

Sadly the standard says the following about initializing members within the body of your class:

> #### 9.2/5 Class members    [class.mem]
>
> A member can be initialized using a *brace-or-equal-initializer*. (For
>   static data members, see 9.4.2; for non-static data members, see
>   12.6.2).

We've already found a little hint about what is and what is not okay to do when initializing members, but to be 100% sure we should continue reading up on what a *brace-or-equal-initializer* really is.

```
8.5/1 Initializers [dcl.init]...

brace-or-equal-initializer:
      = initializer-clause
      braced-init-list

initializer-clause:
      assignment-expression
      braced-init-list

initializer-list:
      initializer-clause ...opt
      initializer-list , initializer-clause ...opt

braced-init-list:
      { initializer-list ,opt }
      { }
```

With the above specification of *braced-or-equal-initializer* we found that we are faced with two options when initializing members within the body of our class, using either a `=` together with an *initializer-clause*, or a `braced-init-list` on it's own.

The above boils down to either of these two:

```
struct Obj {
  Type foo = Type (1,2,3); /* example of an initializer-clause */
  Type bar        {1,2,3}; /* example of a  braced-init-list   */
};
```

---

### *braced-init-list* looks awesome, let's use it!

Since `std::vector<...>` accepts a `std::initializer_list` in one overload of it's constructors we **cannot** use a *braced-init-list* to invoke the constructor taking two arguments `(size_type count, const T& value)`, because that will instead be used as the contents of our *vector*.

We are therefore stuck with using a *initializer-clause*.

<sup>See the previous *hack* for a confirming, but maybe not so obvious, solution.</sup>

Comment: *default valued* members? I'm not sure what the correct term is when you specify default values directly when declaring the variable, and not using the *ctor-initialization-list*. Though the snippet explains itself, even if I'm using the wrong term.

Comment: Members _will be_ default-initialized if they don't appear in the constructor initializer list -- putting them in the constructor initializer list with only `()` as the initializer is _value-initialization_, not default-initialization.

Comment: @ildjarn I'm not talking about the default initialzation of the object, I'm talking about default values assigned to the object inside the encapsulating class.

Comment: I think this post is the best solution among answers so far. Thank you :).

Comment: @ildjarn I changed it, 6 minutes before you made your remark (and I find the wording to be very clear right now).

Comment: "*members set to have a default value in the body of an object requires the use of = when declaring them.*" sounds like you're referring to default-initialization, so if you think it's clear, you're wrong.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb what about now? completely rewrote the post.. hopefully this is better.

Answer (score -2):

### The dreamy solution..

If you just don't want to repeat `std::vector`, how about

```
class A
{
    auto y = std::vector<int>(2,3);
};
```

---

This **is not allowed**, the Standard says (7.1.6.4) `[dcl.spec.auto]`:

> **The `auto` type-specifier can also be used** in declaring a variable in the condition of a selection statement or an iteration statement , in the *type-specifier-seq* in the *new-type-id* or *type-id* of a new-expression, in a *for-range-declaration*, and **in declaring a static data member with a *brace-or-equal-initializer* that appears within the *member-specification* of a class deﬁnition**.

Probably they forgot to update this line when *brace-or-equal-initializer* syntax was added to non-static members.

Comment: hmm.. are you sure about that?

Comment: You quoted it yourself; *"in declaring a **static** data member"*

Comment: @refp: Oh drat, that looks like a future improvement to the Standard.

Comment: They didn't forget to update that line. It was discussed in the committee and considered to be too risky (too ODR sensitive). Another problem is that the brace or equal initializer is parsed when the class is complete, but at that time it needs to know the type of all data members -> chicken and egg.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: But that chicken-and-egg problem applies to all type inference, doesn't it?  I understand the committee not wanting to add such a requirement until there's an existing implementation, which makes me think a future version will add it.

Comment: @BenVoigt can you show another context it applies to? Here's an example exploiting the in-class initialization dilemma: `template<size_t> struct Size {}; struct A { auto size = Size<sizeof(A)>(); };`.

Comment: @Johannes: It should be handled the same as `void f() { auto size = Size<sizeof(size)>(); }`

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, kindof. which is ill-formed too because it does not make sense.